# Dynamically creating Link Labels using foreach in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, nullreferenceexception, linklabel

I am trying to create link labels dynamically using foreach . I am setting the text of each linklabel to a string which is stored in flatestgames string array and whose links are stored in flatestlinks string array.
But it is throwing a null reference exception at the line flg[i].Text = s though s is not set to null.
Please help me out.
Below is the code snippet:

```
if (!(flatestgames == null || flatestgames.Length < 1))
        {
            i = 0;
            LinkLabel[] flg = new LinkLabel[10];
            foreach (string s in flatestgames)
            {
                flg[i].Text = s;
                flg[i].Links.Add(0, s.Length, flatestlinks[i]);
                Point p = new Point(43, 200 + 23 * i);
                flg[i].Location = p;
                flg[i].Visible = true;
                flg[i].Show();
                this.Controls.Add(flg[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `flg[i] = new LinkLabel();` in foreach loop

```
if (!(flatestgames == null || flatestgames.Length < 1))
        {
            i = 0;
            LinkLabel[] flg = new LinkLabel[10];
            foreach (string s in flatestgames)
            {
                flg[i] = new LinkLabel();
                flg[i].Text = s;
                flg[i].Links.Add(0, s.Length, flatestlinks[i]);
                Point p = new Point(43, 200 + 23 * i);
                flg[i].Location = p;
                flg[i].Visible = true;
                flg[i].Show();
                this.Controls.Add(flg[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should include in your answer, where in foreach loop he needs to do this and why. (This is correct btw +1)

Comment: @PrabhanjanBhat - You should update your question with more information then (i.e updated code source)

Comment: ` LinkLabel[] flg = new LinkLabel[10];` will create an array with all has null, 
`foreach (string s in flatestgames)
            {
                flg[i] = new LinkLabel();
                flg[i].Text = s;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the length of your `flatestgames` array less than 10? You have to check this at first and declare your:

`LinkLabel[] flg = new LinkLabel[10];`

as:

`LinkLabel[] flg = new LinkLabel[flatestgames.Length];`

I think you get this exception, because in foreach you try to get more than 10 entities as you declared.